# Get error while running grpc curl in docker

Tags: docker, grpc

Trying to run grpc curl in docker: `docker run fullstorydev/grpcurl api.grpc.me:443 list`

Get error: Failed to dial target host "api.grpc.me:443": dial tcp: lookup api.grpc.me on 192.168.65.7:53: no such host

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images when it's trivial to copy-and-paste text. Images may not outlive questions and provide accessibility challenges.

Comment: `api.grpc.me` does not appear in the public DNS and your machine is unable to resolve the address using its local DNS resolver (`no such host`). As a result, gRPCurl is unable to do anything with the address. If the address is a valid (local) address, you will need to ensure the container's DNS is able to resolve the name.